# Variable from function to function

Tags: function, variables, tkinter

I wanted to have a text inserted in a textbox that is in a toplevel window, but I wanted it to depend on a checkbox if it is ticked or not. For example, if the checkbox is ticked, the textbox will show apple if not it should show orange. I added print in the check_checkbox function to see if something is wrong with  it, it seems that it is working but I cant make it appear in the textbox.

````
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as st

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("100x100")
root.title("Test")



def check_checkbox():
    if isChecked.get() == 1:
        testVar = tk.StringVar(root, "apple")
    else:
        testVar = tk.StringVar(root, "orange")
    print(testVar.get())

def new_win(testVar):
    win = tk.Toplevel(root)
    win.geometry("100x100")
    win.title("Test 2")
    
    win_txt_box = st.ScrolledText(win, height=50, width=50)
    win_txt_box.pack()

    win_txt_box.insert("1.0", f""+testVar+"")
    return;


testVar = tk.StringVar()
isChecked = tk.IntVar()

# checkbox
check_box = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="CHECK THIS",
                                  command=check_checkbox,
                                  variable=isChecked,
                                  onvalue=1,
                                  offvalue=0,)
check_box.grid(column=0, row=0)

# button
test_button = ttk.Button(root, text="CLICK THIS", command=lambda: new_win(testVar.get()))
test_button.grid(column=0, row=1)


root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a global inside function. There are only three changes in line 13, 18 and 28.

```
def check_checkbox():
    global x
    if isChecked.get() == 1:
        testVar = tk.StringVar(root, "apple")
    else:
        testVar = tk.StringVar(root, "orange")
    x = (testVar.get())

def new_win(testVar):
    win = tk.Toplevel(root)
    win.geometry("100x100")
    win.title("Test 2")
    
    win_txt_box = st.ScrolledText(win, height=50, width=50)
    win_txt_box.pack()

    win_txt_box.insert("1.0", x)
    return
```

Result:

[image]]